# Managing Access Rights to an encrypted column

Tags: sql-server, encryption, access-rights

I've been searching for a way to encrypt a column in SQL Server and manage the access rights to the encrypted column.

There are many articles about the former (e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16)), but I can't find anything that explains the latter.

I've been experimenting with a local instance of SQL Server and using SSMS to connect to the DB.

Using a user associated with my Windows Account (Windows Authentication) I created a simple database with one table, then encrypted one of the columns using "Always Encrypted", by selecting "Encrypt Columns" from the SSMS context menu. The encrypted column doesn't contain any keys/indexes.

What I intend to achieve is to create another user and grant it with rights to read and write data to the table with the encrypted column, but NOT being able to decrypt or query the encrypted column.

Then I created a local SQL Server account and grated it with read and write access to the db. However, the local user can still access the data from the encrypted column (I use the "Enable Always Encrypted" connection parameter).

[image: accessrights]

### Question

How can I tweak the access rights for the local user, so that it has read/write access to the table, but can't get the decrypted content of the encrypted column?

Comment: deny right to specific column perhaps?

Comment: I forgot to say: I'm pretty much n00b in MSSQL access rights management :),. @siggemannen did you mean something like `DENY SELECT ON data1.table (column3) TO user1;` ?

Comment: yes, something like that

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll give it a go. But since I can (a) restrict access to a column and (b) in my current setup everyone can access the encrypted column then why bother using column encryption? I guess there must be a better way.

Comment: The idea is that each user that logins either gets or don't get encryption access through certificate or key store or whatever. So, you have to actually have it on your own computer. The sql server admin even shouldn't have access to this cert, so he cannot decrypt the data himself

Answer (score 0):

If the user doesn't has access to the encryption key, they will never see the data in plaintext. The database role db_datareader and db_datawriter will not help in this case. This will allow to user to read encrypted data.

See also [Overview of key management for Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/overview-of-key-management-for-always-encrypted?view=sql-server-ver16)